# How update stub class? (axis2)

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, stub

I created a web service with eclipse indigo, tomcat 7 and i used the axis2. I did a simple calculator for tests and i generate the results using the stub class. All works. The problem is when add a new method in the web service. This new method don't appear in stub class.

How do make for update the stub class?

thanks

sorry my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten to add the operation to the WSDL's binding section. The binding section defines how to access the operation through the protocol (SOAP, etc) which you are using. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/wsdl_binding.asp) is a page which describes the binding section.

If you're using a WSDL editor, it may have a way to automatically generate the binding section for you. With the eclipse graphical WSDL editor for example, you'd click on the binding object and select "Generate binding content...".